# Ideal place for Object identifier

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium-WebDriver-Data Driver Framework, which is the best place for keeping the Object identifier (like Xpath,id,name..etc) and constants (URL, user name, expected result text and etc..) from the below options?

Properties file **or** Excel **or** Class file as "static final"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer Properties files. Just two lines of code, and voila, that's it. No third party APIs required.

```
    Properties CONFIG = new Properties();
    CONFIG.load(new FileInputStream("OR.properties"));
```

Simple as that.

For excel files, you need to script at least 10-15 lines of code, that wastes your precious compilation times, also risking the data integrity, and you are dependent on a third-party API.

And, with putting as class files, the problem is you end up compiling stuff that does not require compilation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: Glad I could help @KannanC. If you feel, this is the answer is helpful, please upvote, and/or if this is the answer to your question, please consider marking this "Accept as Answer".

Comment: I accepted the answer also up-voted, since i have less than 15 reputation, it won't be reflected

Answer (score 0):

Properties files:-

config.properties for -- URL, user name, expected result text and etc
object.properties for --  Xpath,id,name..etc